# check which option value is selected from <select> tag

Tags: php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
     <select name='choose'>
        <option>mango</option>
        <option>banana</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

if i have this option values, how can i know which value is set rather than passing the value.

```
if(is set($_POST['choose'])){
      echo "Something";
}
```

the above is for select tag and it works fine but i tried giving name for both mango and banana but didn't get which value i choose. Anybody help please. Thanks!

Comment: Obs, your if clause has a small issue, it's `isset()` not `is set()` :)

Answer (score 1):

The options need some values, for example:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name='choose'>
<option value="mango" >mango</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
</form>
```

PHP:
Change is set() to [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and added if-else conditions, to handle the different inputs

```
if( isset( $_POST['choose'] ) ){
    if( $_POST['choose'] === "mango" ) {
        echo "do the mango";
    } elseif( $_POST['choose'] === "banana" ) {
        echo "do the banana";
    } else {
        echo "nothing chosen";
    }
}
```

pass it to a varibale

```
$chosen_fruit = "none";

// You can also pass the value to a variable
if( isset( $_POST['choose'] ) ){
    if( $_POST['choose'] === "mango" ) {
        $chosen_fruit = "mango";
    } elseif( $_POST['choose'] === "banana" ) {
       $chosen_fruit = "banana";
    }
} 


// here you can use the value of the variable
echo $chosen_fruit;// echo outside the if condition
```

if you want to need more about variable scopes, take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: okay that's good but i am not going to echo the value inside if condition, i rather pass it to variable and use that variable outside of if condition. am afraid its not possible to use variable outside this kind of if conditions. any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @Nebi SO is not a guiding place, and please don't expand further on your question, ask a new one if you run into problems. (But yes, you can declare variables inside if sentences and use them else where, although you have to be aware that if your code doesn't enter the if clause it won't be set).

Comment: @Nebi: I've updated the answer an linked to the php docs (variable scopes)

Comment: @swidmann, please try it your self, it echos noting! that means $chosen_fruit echos the value that is assigned at the top,  which is none!

Comment: @Nebi, well you have to submit the form =). by the way, this code works, if it does not work in your case you have another issue, maybe provide more code

Answer (score 0):

you must have to set value for every option

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name='choose'>
<option value="mango" >mango</option>
<option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
</form>

if(isset($_POST['choose'])){ //replace is set to isset
echo "Something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
 <option value="mango">mango</option>
 <option value="banana">banana</option>
```

An there is space in `isset` so change it like this:

```
 $data="";
 if(isset($_POST['choose'])){
   $value = $_POST['choose'];
   if($value=="fruitValue") {
    $data = "do_soemthing"; 
   }    
 }
```

`$data` access data  variable here.

Comment: What does your answer bring that isn't all ready covered by the two others? :)

Comment: i know its isset but i kinda correct the spell error, that's why it makes a space. the other is its not echo "do_something" in ma project, its like $do="do something"; and i thinks its not possible to use this $do outside of multiple if conditions! did you get me?

Comment: you can use it... use $do as global...set it in the conditions and then use it out of the conditions..got it @Nebi

Comment: @Danya Sandeelo.. you handled the variable confusion perfectly! $val="";..........if(isset($_POST['choose'])){
   $value = $_POST['choose'];
   if($value=="fruitValue") {
   $val= "do_soemthing"; 
   }    THANKS MAN!
 }  echo $val;

Comment: modifying the answer...mark it as answered then ;-) @Nebi